# checkbox not refreshing its state in a temporary jquery ui dialog

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, checkbox, refresh, checked

I have some checkboxes in the main page; when each of them is clicked, I temporary jquery ui dialog is created with some checkboxes on it (the ones that don't work); I found that first time dialog checkboxes are loaded, they can be checked and unchecked via jquery. If I close and recreate that dialog, I am unable to check or uncheck checkboxes via jquery; I tried with the following methods but with no results (element state changes but checkbox's element on page is not refreshed)

```
$('#checkbox').attr('checked', true);
$('#checkbox').prop('checked', true);
```

Element state changes, I checked it with

```
$('#checkbox').attr('checked');
$('#checkbox').prop('checked');
$('#checkbox').is(':checked');
```

Code is the following:

```
// For each checkbox in a form in main page
$('.first_form_cbox').each(function() 
{
    // When each checkbox is clicked (checked) fun_handler is called,
    // and id of checkbox is passed to it
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    $(this).click({'id': id }, fun_handler); 
});

// Handler for click on main page checkbox
function fun_handler()
{
    // Dialog body is created    
    var dlg_body = '<div class="sfun_container">';
    // Array that holds values used by checkboxes
    var fun_list = new Array( 
        {'name' : 'Minimum, Maximum', 'fun' : 'MMX'},
        {'name' : 'Average', 'fun' : 'AVG'},
        {'name' : 'Standard Deviation', 'fun' : 'STD'},
        {'name' : 'Standard Error of the Mean', 'fun' : 'SEM'},
        {'name' : 'Distinct Count', 'fun' : 'DCNT'}
        );
    // Creates all checkboxes using values defined in fun_list
    for (var f_index in fun_list)
    {
        dlg_body += '<input id="tfun_cbox_' + fun_list[f_index]['fun'] 
            + '" type="checkbox" class="tfun_cbox" value="'
            + fun_list[f_index]['fun'] + '"/>' 
            + fun_list[f_index]['name'] + '<br/>';
    }
    dlg_body += '</div>';
    // Creates temporary dialog
    $('<div title="Select function(s)"><p>' + dlg_body + '</p></div>').dialog(
    {
        modal : true,
        width : 320,
        resizable : false,
        // When open
        open : function ()
        {
            // Gets from data-funs attribute of main page checkbox
            // Each main page checkbox may have some functions already
            // inserted in data-funs, if earlier some dialog checkboxes,
            // that represent functions, were checked and their values
            // saved in data-funs
            var funs = $('#' + event.data['id']).data('funs');
            if (funs != undefined)
            {
                // Retrieves from funs which dialog checkboxes were checked
                for(var f_index in funs)
                {
                    // Checks dialog checkbox
                    $('#tfun_cbox_' + funs[f_index]).prop('checked', true);
                }
            }
        },
        close : function ()
        {
            if ($('.tfun_cbox:checkbox:checked').length > 0)
            {
                // Some dialog checkboxes are checked
                var funs = new Array();
                $('.tfun_cbox:checkbox:checked').each(function()
                {
                    // Saves dialog checked checkbox state value in funs
                    funs.push($(this).val());
                    // Unchecks dialog checkbox
                    $(this).prop('checked', false);
                });
                // Saves all checkboxes value in data-funs of main page
                // checkbox
                $('#' + event.data['id']).data('funs', funs);
            }
        },
        buttons : [
        {
            text : "Ok",
            click : function()
            {
                // Checks back main page checkbox that 
                // when clicked fired fun_handler
                $('#' + event.data['id']).prop('checked', true);
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        },
        {
            text : "Cancel",
            click : function()
            {
                // Unchecks all dialog checkboxes in order not to save them
                $('.tfun_cbox:checkbox:checked').prop('checked', false);
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }]
    });    
}
```

I'll post more code if needed.
Thanks

Comment: Could you please provide a fiddle or some more code how you are opening this dialog for first time and second time

Comment: I am unable to create a fiddle with dialogs.. so I am posting more code..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to don't use an id selector but a class one. I mean don't select for $('#checkbox') but for $('.mycheckbox'). If not you are creating two objects with the same id, and in the second call probably JQuery refers to the old one.

Comment: It's a valid workaround. However I'm thinking about using a normal dialog (not temporary) because I'm not sure where it goes when closed, I mean, if it's destroyed or not; so maybe there's a conflict with the old one. Thanks :)

Comment: I ended up putting `$(this).remove();` at the end of `close` callback; temporary dialog was not destroyed probably..

Answer (score 1):

I might be wrong since I am not completely aware on how the jqueryui dialogs works, but if you are trying to attach events on some DOM elements that they get destroyed and then recreated they obviously lose all the events bounded on them.
I would probably use [`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) or [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) directives if I need to handle event of future DOM elements.

Comment: I read the documentation about `.on()` and you are right about using a delegate. Anyway I think the problem is related to first created dialog that never gets destroyed (and leaves its checkboxes alive but not visible, so the selector gets them instead of new ones). Thanks for your tip :)